# mysql shows chinese characters like squares

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding

I want to save chinese characters in mysql db, charset is set to `UTF8` via connecting to db, also the field's charset is `utf8`, and collation - `utf8_general_ci`,

But instead of the word it shows squares. I use sqlyog.

There is one thing, if I make request and echo the word in the browser if shows the right chinese word.

So, I am wondering why it shows the correct word in browser, when in db it is like squares and vice versa.
I am afraid that maybe via exporting or importing in the future I can have some data lose.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data might be **stored correctly** in the DB, but **read wrongly** by sqlyog.

I haven't used sqlyog, but this problem might be because of the way sqlyog connects to MySQL - look for parameters in sqlyog connection to DB that are related to character set and make sure they are also utf8

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have a bunch of other languages like Russian, Armenian, Hindi and a lot more, but all they are shown correctly, only the chinese is wrong. Thanks

Comment: I guess you were right, by phpmyadmin it showed right, so in all probability the problem is related to sqlyog. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I had to insert Latin characters to the database, I used mb_convert_encoding($str, 'utf8', 'HTML-ENTITIES') and it got stored correctly in the database and wen I had to show it in the html page I just had the encoding=utf-8